# icon onClick issue

Tags: reactjs, meteor, onclick, icons

i have two icons that determine the view of a bunch of components in my Meteor React project

currently, I wrap both in a span with a specific onClick function for each icon. is there some way to handle this with just one function, passing in an id as a prop?

I want to have something like:

```
<span id="grid" onClick={this.handleViewBtnClick.bind(this, id)}> 
  <i className="fa fa-th" ></i>
</span> 
<span id="list" onClick={this.handleViewBtnClick.bind(this, id)}>
  <i className="fa fa-align-justify" ></i>
</span>
```

And:

```
handleViewBtnClick(id) {
  this.setState({
  view: id
  })
}
```

but that doesn't produce the desired outcome, and neither does any other thing I tried. the only time I got it to work was when I wrapped both icons in a `button` instead of a span. I guess I could make it transparent, but is there a way to do this wrapping it in `span` or not at all?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. Let me try again.

Comment: I guess you wanted to include an id="grid" in the el. In any case, it doesn't work (Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined).

Comment: Also you shouldn't bind handler functions inside `render()`. It's best practice to either do it [in the constructor or with property initializer syntax](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) if you use babel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use arrow functions:

```
<span id="grid" onClick={() => this.handleViewBtnClick('first-id')}> 
    <i className="fa fa-th" ></i>
</span> 
<span id="list" onClick={() => this.handleViewBtnClick('second-id')}> 
    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" ></i>
</span>
```